# Iterate Through JPanel Components In Hashmap

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I've got a Hashmap of JPanel components and I'm trying to iterate through and style, i've done this in the past with JButtons on a JPanel but i'm having trouble getting the JLabel-specific attributes. The code i've got:

```
 for (Component item : imageAreas.values()) {
        // Style components item.setBorder(BorderFactory...);
    }
```

The problem being there is no setBorder() attribute for components, is there any way I can cast the component item to JPanel in the for loop? - I've tried adding `(JLabel)` in front of everything but it doesn't like that. The imageAreas is the hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way I can cast the component item to JPanel?

```
JPanel panel = (JPanel)item;
item.setBorder(...);
```

The above assumes that you do indeed have JPanels in the Hashmap.

The question is why are you use a Hashmap that contains Components, when you can use a Hashmap that contains JPanels? To create the HashMap you can do something like:

```
HashMap<String, JPanel> imageAreas = new HashMap<String, JPanel>();
```

Then to access the panels you can do:

```
for (JPanel panel : imageAreas.values()) {
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory...);
}
```

Comment: Ah ha! - no errors and yes its just JPanels - thanks!

Comment: You know I never considered that ... why didn't i just use JPanels .. good question indeed :L - you have any idea about the second problem I'm now having?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct about why this error is occurring ("there is no setBorder() attribute for components"), and you're on the right track about casting to `JPanel`.

> I've tried adding (JPanel) in front of everything but it doesn't like that.

This is probably because some of the components in your array are not `JPanel`s, so a `ClassCastException` is thrown when you try to cast them to `JPanel`. So, you need to check first:

```
for (Component item : imageAreas.values()) {
    if (item.instanceOf(JPanel.class)) { 
       JPanel pan = (JPanel)item;
       pan.setBorder(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant to type "JLabel" not JPanel - typo :P